# Como usar correctamente la propiedad filter en imagenes png CSS3

Tags: html5, css3

Ya se que esto se podria hacer con otros programas, pero me ha causado curiosidad en CSS.
Como veran `img-amarillo` tiene el mismo `filter` que `img2-amarillo`, sin embargo en la primera no cambia de color y en la segunda si porque pasa esto?
(los valores que le puse al filter es el HSL del color amarillo)

```css
#img
{background-image: url(http://pluspng.com/img-png/vector-icon-png-free-vector-icons-in-svg-psd-png-eps-format-or-as-icon-font-thousands-of-free-icons-in-the-largest-database-of-free-vector-icons-812.png);
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center
}
#img-amarillo
{background-image: url(http://pluspng.com/img-png/vector-icon-png-free-vector-icons-in-svg-psd-png-eps-format-or-as-icon-font-thousands-of-free-icons-in-the-largest-database-of-free-vector-icons-812.png);
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
filter: hue-rotate(60deg) brightness(500%) saturate(100%);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center
}
#img2
{background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXKdt.png);
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center
}
#img2-amarillo
{background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXKdt.png);
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
filter: hue-rotate(60deg) brightness(500%) saturate(100%);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center
}
```

```html
<div id="img"></div>
<div id="img-amarillo"></div>
<div id="img2"></div>
<div id="img2-amarillo"></div>
```

`

Comment: En la primera (`#img-amarillo`) has puesto `filter:filter:`. Tienes un error tipográfico, propongo el cierre de la pregunta.

Comment: ya lo corregi pero sigue igual

Comment: Ok, retiro el voto de cierre y miro de nuevo.

Comment: Vale, el problema es que el filtro en la imagen negra no hace nada.

Comment: Bueno tienes razon al haber probado con otra imagen de color rojo surgio el efecto que queria, gracias

Comment: Prueba con cualquier imagen que no sea negra y verás que te funciona.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema que sufres es debido a que los colores blancos y negros puros no tienen definido el matiz (puede ser cualquiera), por lo que el giro no los afecta.

Multiplicar por 5 el brillo del negro (500%) no tiene tampoco efecto (0 x 5 = 0).

En la segunda imagen sí funciona porque el rojo (0º) al girarlo 60º da amarillo:

[image: círculo cromático]

Comment: gracias entendi perfectamente